How Come The 'Timeout" Feature Breaks The Rest Of My Game (It prevents the user from inputting an answer) (Python
I hate to input the entire code here, but I am not sure where the problem is located. The answer system worked before, but when I inplemented a timer to answer questions, it suddenly stopped displaying "Correct!" and "Incorrect!" and instead simply disaplys "Times Up!"
import random
import time
from colorama import *
timer = 5
while True:
  color_dict = {
    "1" : "Red",
    "2" : "Blue",
    "3" : "Light Blue",
    "4" : "Green",
    "5" : "Cyan",
    "6" : "Yellow",
    "7" : "Magenta",
  }
  def wait_timer_for_stress():
    global timer
    timer = 5
    while timer > 0:
      timer -= 1
      time.sleep(0.5)
  startcolor = [Fore.RED, Fore.GREEN, Fore.BLUE, Fore.YELLOW, Fore.MAGENTA, Fore.CYAN, Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX]
  print(random.choice(startcolor) + "Type the number, not   the color!\n\n" + Fore.RESET)
  print(Fore.RED + "1 = Red\n" + 
    Fore.BLUE + "2 - Blue\n" + 
    Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "3 - Light Blue\n" + 
    Fore.GREEN + "4 = Green\n" + 
    Fore.CYAN + "5 = Cyan\n" + 
    Fore.YELLOW + "6 = Yellow\n" + 
    Fore.MAGENTA + "7 = Magenta\n")
  words = ["Red", "Green", "Light Blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Magenta", "Cyan"]
  word = random.choice(words)
  color = random.choice(startcolor)
  print(color + word + Fore.RESET)
  wait_timer_for_stress()
  if timer > 0:
    answer = input(Fore.WHITE + "\n\n")
    if answer in color_dict:
      if color_dict[answer] == word:
        print(Fore.GREEN + "\n\n\nCorrect!\n\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)
      else:
        print(Fore.RED + "\n\n\nIncorrect!\n\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
      print(Fore.RED + "\n\n\nIncorrect!\n\n\n")
      time.sleep(1)
  else:
      print(Fore.RED + "\n\n\nTimes Up!\n\n\n")
      time.sleep(1)


Your program can only do one thing at a time. When it waits for the timer to run down, it waits for the timer to run down. It won't do anything else during that time, including accepting input. If you want to do two things at a time, you need to look into threading.

Your code is running your while timer > 0 all the time. It is not running your other code. This means it is just running the timer until it runs out then displaying time's up. You could try putting that while loop in your mainloop, or find another way to do it. I mean putting your timer function inside of you main loop. This is what I mean:
import time
start = 5
while True:
    start = start -1
    time.sleep(1)
    if start == 0
        break

This will give you a five second timer and break the loop when it reaches zero. To change how long the timer is, you could make the start variable shorter or longer.

I apologize for asking, but could you please clarify what you mean by putting the "while" loop with the main loop?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Python runs on only 1 thread, without threading (as far as I am aware). As such,  while timer > 0 takes up that entire thread. The thread doesn't wait for the timer to finish while doing other tasks, it waits for the while timer > 0 loop to return then continues. You should use threading instead.
Here's your script when using threading:
import random, time, threading, os
from colorama import *
timer = 5
kill_input = False

def wait_timer_for_stress():
    global timer, answered
    timer = 5
    while timer > 0 and not answered:
        timer -= 1
        time.sleep(0.5)

def get_input():
    global timer, answered, kill_input
    answered = False
    while timer > 0 and not kill_input:
            if kill_input:
                break

            answer = input(Fore.WHITE + "\n\n: ")
            if answer in color_dict:
                if color_dict[answer] == word:
                    answered = True
                    print(Fore.GREEN + "\n\n\nCorrect!\n\n\n")
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    answered = True
                    print(Fore.RED + "\n\n\nIncorrect!\n\n\n")
                    time.sleep(1)
            else:
                answered = True
                print(Fore.RED + "\n\n\nIncorrect!\n\n\n")
                time.sleep(1)
    
    

while True:
    color_dict = {
        "1" : "Red",
        "2" : "Blue",
        "3" : "Light Blue",
        "4" : "Green",
        "5" : "Cyan",
        "6" : "Yellow",
        "7" : "Magenta",
    }
    kill_input = False
    print(Fore.RESET,end="")
    startcolor = [Fore.RED, Fore.GREEN, Fore.BLUE, Fore.YELLOW, Fore.MAGENTA, Fore.CYAN, Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX]
    print(random.choice(startcolor) + "Type the number, not the color!\n\n" + Fore.RESET)
    print(Fore.RED + "1 = Red\n" + 
        Fore.BLUE + "2 - Blue\n" + 
        Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "3 - Light Blue\n" + 
        Fore.GREEN + "4 = Green\n" + 
        Fore.CYAN + "5 = Cyan\n" + 
        Fore.YELLOW + "6 = Yellow\n" + 
        Fore.MAGENTA + "7 = Magenta\n")
    words = ["Red", "Green", "Light Blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Magenta", "Cyan"]
    word = random.choice(words)
    color = random.choice(startcolor)
    print(color + word + Fore.RESET)
    thread_timer = threading.Thread(target=wait_timer_for_stress)
    for_input = threading.Thread(target=get_input)
    for_input.start()
    thread_timer.start()
    

    thread_timer.join() # wait for the timer to finish, thread "get_input" still runs in the background

    if not answered:
        print(Fore.RED + "\n\n\nTimes Up!\n\n\n")
        
        time.sleep(1)
    kill_input = True
    os.system("cls") # use os.system("clr") for UNIX systems

